# What is mm-qcamera-daemon?

Tags: camera, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

After my camera app crashed this process is running and consuming 42% of battery but today morning it disappeared but still my battery is draining out too quickly! Even restart doesn't help.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

How can I get things back to normal?

Comment: Have you tried updating or is this a known issue - have you investigated? as for that is a camera service running in the background.

Comment: Yes, i am running on 4.4.2. I also checked under running applications there were no applications running which uses camera.